# Fix scrollbox length on the vertical scrollbar [Visual Studio 2019]

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Using Visual Studio 2019 Professional (and if relevant, editing C#). While using the IDE, the `Scrollbox` on the vertical scrollbar keeps changing size depending on where you are in the document. It might be smaller at the bottom and then get bigger as you scroll upwards or vice versa. This is disconcerting and makes navigation harder.

In the image below, `Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors > Overview background` is set to `Maroon` to better show the `Scrollbox` in case there is ambiguity. The `Scrollbox` is the bit between the orange lines which you can grab to scroll up and down.

[image: Scrollbox]

In `Notepad++`, the `Scrollbox` size depends on the height of the application and the number of lines in the text file being edited. The size (correctly) changes size when you add or remove lines, but it does **not** change size dynamically depending on where you are in the document. This is the functionality I'm looking for.

A [related Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57063575/visual-studio-vertical-scrollbar-changes-length-based-on-amount-of-text-on-scree) suggested disabling `Edit > Advanced > Word Wrap`. This does not resolve the issue.

How do you turn off "dynamic `Scrollbox` sizing while scrolling"?

Answer (score 1):

When the IDE is in `Map mode`, it does not appear to be possible to fix the `Scrollbox` height.

To resolve this issue, go to `Options > Text Editor > All Languages > Scroll Bars > Behaviour`, and select `Use bar mode for vertical scroll bar`.